# Subtracting using minus function in alloy

Tags: subtraction, alloy

I have created a vending machine it works fine. I want to subtract 1 from the quantity of items once the transaction is completed. I have provided comments in my code for understanding. Ignore some of the comments in pred chocolate. Somehow I am trying to subtract but it just wont. I don't know what seems to be the problem. Any help is appreciated .

```
sig button {
        qty:Int}  // buttons on vending machine for selecting chocolates

//sig coin{}

sig choco{ 
    value:Int, // Each chocolate has some cost as an attribute aka value.
    choice :one button // Selecting option
            }
fact {
    //  all c:choco | all c1:choco -c | c1.choice != c.choice
        }
sig machine{
    cust : one customer, // Customer entity
    a,b,c,d,nullb ,ip: one button, // buttons on vending machine  ,ip is the input selected by user
    //oners,twors,fivers ,tenrs,null1: set coin,
        ipp,opc2 : one Coin, // ipp = input rs , opc = balance rs
    customeripb: cust one -> one ip, // customer presses a button
    customeripc: cust one -> one ipp, // customer enters coins
    customeropc:  opc2 one -> one cust, //customer receives balance of coins 
    op: one choco , // output of chocolate from machine
    customerop:  op one -> one cust, // customer receives a chocolate

    cadbury, kitkat, eclairs , gum,null: lone choco // types of chocolate
    }

{
  //#(fivers+tenrs+null+twors+oners) = 5 
  #(a+b+c+d) = 4 // no of buttons of a b c and d are 4 on machine
    #   (cadbury+kitkat+ eclairs +gum) =4 // no of options to choose = 4
    cadbury=choice.a // cadbury corresponds to button a
    cadbury.value= 10 // cadbury costs 10rs
        kitkat=choice.b // kitkat corresponds to button b
        kitkat.value=5 // kitkat costs 5rs
        null.value=0 // null costs 0 rs
        null=choice.nullb 
// as such null doesnt exist it is just to specify no i/p no o/p and nulb is an imaginary button
        eclairs=choice.c // eclairs corresponds to button c
        eclairs.value=1 // eclairs costs 1 rs
        gum=choice.d // gum corresponds to button d
            gum.value=2 // gum costs 1 rs
            a.qty>=10 and a.qty<=40
            b.qty>=11 and b.qty<=40
            c.qty>=12 and c.qty<=40
            d.qty>=13 and d.qty<=40

            nullb.qty=0
    //ip=nullb  //input button selection is never nullb(which is imaginary button)
    ipp.value!=0 // input of coins is never = 0rs

/*  all m:machine|all o:opc2
     |all opp: op| all i:ip|all ii:ipp| all c:m.cust
   |c -> i in m.customeripb and c->ii in m.customeripc and o->c in m.customerop and opp->c in m.customerop
    */ 
    //button=!=none
}

sig customer //user of machine
{
}


abstract sig Coin { //each coin has a valueof rs
  value: Int
}

sig Nullrs extends Coin {} { value = 0 } // void rs
sig Oners extends Coin {} { value = 1 } // one rs
sig Twors extends Coin {} { value = 2 } // twors
sig Fivers extends Coin {}{ value = 5 } // five rs
sig Tenrs extends Coin {} { value = 10 } // ten rs

sig Threers extends Coin {} { value = 3 } // this is only used in o/p to specify 3rs will come out
sig Fourrs extends Coin {} { value = 4 }// this is only used in o/p to specify 4rs will come out
sig Sixrs extends Coin {} { value = 6 }// this is only used in o/p to specify 6rs will come out
sig Sevenrs extends Coin {}{ value = 7 }// this is only used in o/p to specify 7rs will come out
sig Eightrs extends Coin {} { value = 8 } // this is only used in o/p to specify 8rs will come out
sig Niners extends Coin {} { value = 9} //// this is only used in o/p to specify 9rs will come out


pred show{} // show

pred chocolate [before,after:machine ] // machine has two states one before o/p and one after 
    {

    before.cadbury=after.cadbury
    before.kitkat=after.kitkat
    before.eclairs=after.eclairs
    before.gum=after.gum

    //all chocolates will not change and are fixed 

    before.ipp.value=after.ipp.value 
 // input value of rs remains same i.e i/p is inside machine once inputed so it cant change 
    before.opc2.value=0 // before state o/p value of balance coins =0
    before.op=before.null  // beforestate o/p = no chocolate
    before.ip!=before.nullb // input button pressed  never equals nullb
    after.ip!=after.nullb //  input button pressed  never equals nullb
    //before.ip=after.ip // input button pressed remains same 
    after.op=after.kitkat or after.op=after.eclairs
        before.null=after.null // imaginary null chocolate remains in same state 

before.opc2!=none and after.opc2 !=none 
// balance of coins is never empty in case of empty I have defined nullrs


   (after.op.value=before.ipp.value=>after.opc2.value=0)
    //
    (after.op=after.null=>after.opc2.value=before.ipp.value)
    (before.ipp.value > after.op.value=>after.opc2.value=before.ipp.value-after.op.value)

    //(before.ipp.value=after.op.value=>after.opc2.value=0)

    //opc2.value!=ipp.value
    before.ip=before.a or before.ip=before.b or before.ip=before.c or before.ip=before.d 
    (after.op=after.cadbury ) => ( ( after.ip=after.a  and after.a.qty=minus[before.a.qty,1])) else
(after.op=after.kitkat ) => ( (after.ip=after.b and after.b.qty=minus[before.b.qty,  1])) else
(after.op=after.eclairs ) =>( (after.ip=after.c  and after.c.qty=minus[before.c.qty,1])) else
(after.op=after.gum ) =>((after.ip=after.d  and after.d.qty=minus[before.d.qty,1])) else
(after.ip=before.ip and after.ip.qty=minus[before.ip.qty,0] )
after.op!=before.null => after.op.choice=before.ip
    (after.op=before.gum=>before.ipp.value>=Twors.value)

    after.op=before.cadbury=>before.ipp.value>=Tenrs.value
    after.op=before.eclairs=>before.ipp.value>=Oners.value
    after.op=before.kitkat=>before.ipp.value>=Fivers.value

(before.ipp=Oners or before.ipp=Twors or before.ipp=Fivers or before.ipp=Tenrs or before.ipp=Nullrs) and
before.ipp!=Threers and before.ipp!=Fourrs and before.ipp !=Sixrs and before.ipp!=Sevenrs and before.ipp!=Eightrs and before.ipp!=Niners

(before.ip=before.b and before.ipp.value < 5) => (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.eclairs or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.gum)and after.op=before.null 
(before.ip=before.d and before.ipp.value < 2) => (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.eclairs or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.gum)and after.op=before.null 
(before.ip=before.a and before.ipp.value < 10 )=> (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.eclairs or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.gum) and after.op=before.null
(before.ip=before.c and before.ipp.value >= 1) => (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.null or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.gum) and after.op=before.eclairs
(before.ip=before.c and before.ipp.value = 0) => (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.null or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.gum) and after.op=before.null
(before.ip=before.a and before.ipp.value =10) => (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.null or after.op!=before.eclairs or after.op!=before.gum) and after.op= before.cadbury
(before.ip=before.d and before.ipp.value >= 2) => (after.op!=before.kitkat or after.op!=before.null or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.eclairs) and after.op=before.gum
(before.ip=before.b and before.ipp.value >= 5) => (after.op!=before.eclairs or after.op!=before.null or after.op!=before.cadbury or after.op!=before.gum) and after.op=before.kitkat


}

run chocolate for exactly 2 machine, 8 button, 5 choco,9 Int,5 Coin,1 customer
```

Comment: Adding open util/integer  at start also doesn't work.

Comment: Just check the line with the minus function. It seems to be ok to me. Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it would make sense to be more specific than "it doesn't work".

I'm assuming that what you mean by "it doesn't work" is that in the `after` machine you expect the quantity of the selected chocolate to be decreased by 1, but instead, it stays the same. The reason for that is your `(if-then-else) or (if-then-else) or ...` expression, which is logically flawed.  What you probably wanted to express is to enforce at least one `then` branch (because you know that exactly one if condition will be satisfied), but that is not necessary to satisfy this whole disjunction.

More concretely, in

```
((after.op=after.cadbury) 
   =>   (... and after.a.qty=minus[before.a.qty,1] and ...) 
   else (... and after.a.qty=before.a.qty and ...)
) 
or
((after.op=after.kitkat) 
   =>   (... and after.b.qty=minus[before.b.qty,1] and ...) 
   else (... and after.b.qty=before.b.qty and ...)
)
```

even if `after.op` is equal to `after.cadbury`, that does not enforce the then branch of that clause to be true, because to satisfy this whole expression, it is enough to satisfy the else branch of the next clause, which says that all quantities should stay the same.

What you want is some soft of `if-then-elsif-...-else` construct, e.g.,

```
(after.op = after.cadbury) => {
   ...
} else (after.op = after.kitkat) => {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

If you do that, your machine will still not work, that is, your model will become unsatisfiable: your constraints enforce that both `after` and `before` machines share the same buttons<sup>1</sup> and quantities are associated with buttons (the `qty` field is in the `button` sig), which means that quantities must be the same in both `after` and `before` machines.  I don't really see any good reason to put `qty` in sig `button`.

[1]: by having `before.cadbury=after.cadbury and ...` in your `chocolate` predicate, and `cadbury=choice.a and ...` in your appended facts for sig `machine`

Comment: Please can you also suggest with what should I associate the qty field.

Comment: Wanted to handle some kind of quantity parameter of the vending machine . When I used qty for chocolates it showed inconsistent bcoz the no of integers I supplied were not enough to produce the result and when i increased the no of integers it used to show cannot produce the o/p as the no of instances to be processed are out of alloy's handling capabilities and contact mit for more info. Insted I just used a count for money left in machine which would require only two integers. and it worked. Thanks a tonne :)